# Check if the RadButton was clicked from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a little problem I'm tring to fire modal popup from code behind only if the user clicked on the rad button how can I do this?

```
Protected Sub GenerateLinks()
    'If btnAddNewPerson.value = 1 Then
          ' ''Open RadWindow
          Dim script As String = "function f(){$find(""" + modalPopup.ClientID + """).show(); Sys.Application.remove_load(f);}Sys.Application.add_load(f);"
          ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "key", script, True)
          Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

***aspx code***

```
<telerik:RadButton ID="btnAddNewPerson" runat="server" Visible="false" 
    Value="1" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="Add Person" 
    AutoPostBack="false" OnClientClicking="showDialogInitially">
        <Icon PrimaryIconCssClass="rbAdd" PrimaryIconLeft="4" PrimaryIconTop="4" />
</telerik:RadButton>
```

the problem that its always get the value I want to check before if the the button was clicked any idea how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the click event of the button...

```
Protected Sub btnAddNewPerson_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e as ButtonClickEventArgs) Handles butAddNewPerson.Click
...your code here to open Rad Window
End Sub
```

You can also use RadWindowManager to open the window instead of the Script.... see Telerik examples of RadWindowManager